# how to reference a file inside an app script

Tags: google-apps-script

is it possible to reference / import a file that is inside the script.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script src="/testsrc.html"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onLoad()">
  <div>
    <p id='result'>....</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

testsrc.html

```
function onLoad(){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "ran";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('testsrc').getContent() ?>
```

instead of

```
<script src="/testsrc.html"></script>
```

Don't forget to wrap all your js code in **testsrc.html** file in `<script></script>`

PS: better yet in your **code.gs** file create an *include()* function like this

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

then you can call it any time you need to include any file:

```
<?!= include('testsrc') ?>
```